# Argument Line Option Parsing for C

Tags: c, getopt, unistd.h

I've looked at many of the questions asked here before, and I've decided to go with *unistd.h* for *getopt*.

However I have a need that a certain option depends on a previous option, as in

```
exe -a a_opt -b b_bopt
```

where the `-b` will do `b_opt/a_opt`

So it follows that `-a` must be parsed before `-b`.

Is there a way to implement this?

Thanks

EDIT: The simple way is to create a flag and check it at the end, however i'm trying to see if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there's really no such way to enforce argument order using only [`getopt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html).

What you *can* do is to set a flag when `getopt` returns the `-a` option to you, and check that flag when you get the `-b` option.

Comment: Yeah that's what i thought as well. I hoped that there was something elegant.

Answer (score 0):

In `getopt` there is no meaning for the parameters order. The common way to do it is to have one big `switch` case for `getopt` which sets various flags, and after it you can add further dependency checks of the flags.